# Why is this recursion slow?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to solve the problem:

> How many ways are there to get $50 using only 1c, 5c, 10c, 25c, or 50c coins?

Here's my code:

```
main = print $ coinCombinations [1,5,10,25,50] !! 5000

coinCombinations coins = foldr recurse (1 : repeat 0) coins
  where recurse a xs = take a xs ++ zipWith (+) (drop a xs) (recurse a xs)
```

It turns out that my `recurse` function is slow, maybe quadratic time or worse. But I don't understand why, since it looks similar to the fibonacci list

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Comment: Just guessing this has a lot to do with your using take and drop at every step of your recursion. These are "O(a)" functions, maybe trying with splitAt would be a better choice?. Also, keep in mind that ++ is also an "O(a)" operation, as concatenation is not done using pointer arithmetic, but by traversing the whole structure.

Comment: I thought it could be that, but then I tried a simpler `recurseone xs = head xs : zipWith (+) (tail xs) (recurseone xs)` and it was still slow

Comment: Do you understand why your code is correct in the first place? Often you can infer ressource usage (that is, a complexity bound) from a correctness proof (the "termination" part of the correctness property).

Comment: You aren't sharing any work between your calls to `recurse`.  If you said `recurse a xs = let l = take a xs ++ zipWith (+) (drop a xs) l in l`, it would be more like the `fibs` example. 'not saying this would make it fast because you are also not sharing work between the calls of `recurse` in the `foldr`. You can, however, exploit laziness to get a slick implementation of dynamic programming.

Comment: Does your code actually terminate? This line makes it seem like it shouldn't: `recurse a xs = take a xs ++ zipWith (+) (drop a xs) (recurse a xs)` because you'd be computing `recurse a xs` which requires you to compute `recurse a xs`. There isn't a base case.

Comment: Derek: Thanks! That actually made the code way faster.

Comment: @user3217013 In lazy lists, it's more important that the recursion is productive than well-founded. I mean, `let x=1:x in take 100 x` will terminate because `1:x` is productive. The posted `fibs` uses the same trick. In the OP code, I guess the part `take a xs ++ ...` is what should make it productive (if `a`>0 and `xs` not null).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with recursion is that care needs to be taken not to branch exponentially or have exponential memory foot-print; and also writing a *tail recursive* function is usually less expressive.

You can bypass the entire recursion overhead by dynamic programming; which has a very performant implementation in Haskell using a right fold:

```
count :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t Int -> Int -> a
count coins total = foldr go (1: repeat 0) coins !! total
    where
    go coin acc = out where out = zipWith (+) acc $ replicate coin 0 ++ out
```

then:

```
\> count [1, 5, 10, 25, 50] 5000
432699251
```

or as in [31st problem of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31) <sup>(1)</sup>:

```
\> count [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200] 200
73682
```

A *less* efficient alternative would be to use *immutable non-strict (boxed) arrays*:

```
import Data.Array (listArray, (!))

count :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t Int -> Int -> a
count coins total = foldr go init coins ! total
    where
    init = listArray (0, total) $ 1: repeat 0
    go coin arr = out
        where
        out = listArray (0, total) $ map inc [0..total]
        inc i = arr ! i + if i < coin then 0 else out ! (i - coin)
```

---

<sub>(1) The problem is already posted elsewhere on stackoverflow; see [Using dynamic programming in Haskell? [Warning: ProjectEuler 31 solution inside]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871308)</sub>

Comment: That looks almost exactly like my code + Derek's edit... Only difference is you add zeros in front, then add, whereas I use `take a xs` for the front. So I think it would give the same performance.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, this is quadratic time. The problem is that

```
+------------+
v            v
foo a = bar (foo a)
```

is not the same thing as

```
foo a = r
          +-------+
          v       v
    where r = bar r
```

In the first case, the two `foo` functions refer to the same object, but in the second, the *result* of `foo` refers to the same object. So in the first case, if `bar` wants to refer to part of `foo a` it has already computed, it has to compute the whole thing again.